# What is the difference between package import and file import?

Tags: flutter, dart

can somebody explain me the actual difference between these two scenarios-

```
import 'package:app/src/Library/model/AllDocs.dart';
```

and

```
import 'model/AllDocs.dart';
```

or

```
import '../../fileName.dart';
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no performance differences or anything like that.

But it's better to use package paths because you won't need to edit all of your imports in case you move your file to another location (as they're not relative paths).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no difference in importing method for both except the path
I suggest [that](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-an-import-and-a-package-in-Java#:%7E:text=The%20package%20is%20a%20way,the%20application%20will%20not%20run.)